# Is there a function in R to get closest next quarter end date for a given date?

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I am trying to find out closest next quarter end date for a given date in R.
For example, if the input is "2022-02-23", the output should be "2022-03-31"
and if the input is "2022-03-07", the output should be "2022-06-30".
If the input is "2021-12-15", the output should be "2022-03-31".
Is there any function in R for this?

Comment: I don't really follow these examples. `2022-03-07` goes to `2022-06-30` ? Why wouldn't March 7 go to March 31 as the next quarter end date?

Comment: This is the requirement. All the dates from Dec, Jan & Feb go to Mar 31st. All the dates from Mar, Apr & May go to Jun 30th. All the dates from Jun, Jul & Aug go to Sep 30th. All the dates from Sep, Oct & Nov go to Dec 31st.

Comment: Okay, it would be good to be clear and add those details to the question then. A standard 'quarter' i would interpret as Jan-Mar; Apr-Jun etc.

Answer (score 2):

[`lubridate::quarter`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/quarter.html) with argument `type = "date_last"` will get you most of the way there. From the comments, it looks like you want to jump to the following quarter if the date is in the last month of a quarter; we can achieve this by adding a month to each date before passing to `quarter`. We can add months safely using the [`%m+%`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/mplus.html) operator.

```
library(lubridate)

dates_in <- ymd(c("2022-02-23", "2022-03-07", "2021-12-15"))

dates_out <- quarter(dates_in %m+% months(1), type = "date_last")

dates_out
# "2022-03-31" "2022-06-30" "2022-03-31"
```

Comment: Looks like I misread his odd requirement, +1 nice job

Answer (score 1):

Please see this kind of function using lubridate's quarter function

```
last_day_in_quarter <- function(d){
  require(lubridate)
  last_month_in_quarter <- ymd(paste(year(d),quarter(d)*3,1))
  return(last_month_in_quarter %m+% months(1) - 1)
} 
last_day_in_quarter(ymd("2021-12-15")) #"2021-12-31"
last_day_in_quarter(ymd("2022-02-15")) #"2022-03-31"
last_day_in_quarter(ymd("2021-05-15")) #"2021-06-30"
last_day_in_quarter(ymd("2021-07-15")) #"2021-09-30"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think these kinds of problems become immensely easier to understand if you work with a true year-quarter-day type. There is one of these in the [clock](https://clock.r-lib.org) package (I am the author).

```r
library(clock)

x <- date_parse(c("2022-02-23", "2022-03-07", "2021-12-15"))
x
#> [1] "2022-02-23" "2022-03-07" "2021-12-15"

# What quarter are we in now?
yqd <- as_year_quarter_day(x)
yqd
#> <year_quarter_day<January><day>[3]>
#> [1] "2022-Q1-54" "2022-Q1-66" "2021-Q4-76"

# Is the current month the same as the end-of-quarter month?
# (if so, we are going to shift forward by 1 quarter).
shift <- get_month(x) == get_month(as.Date(set_day(yqd, "last")))
shift
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

# Shift by 1 quarter where applicable
yqd[shift] <- yqd[shift] + duration_quarters(1)
yqd
#> <year_quarter_day<January><day>[3]>
#> [1] "2022-Q1-54" "2022-Q2-66" "2022-Q1-76"

# Set day to end of quarter
yqd <- set_day(yqd, "last")
yqd
#> <year_quarter_day<January><day>[3]>
#> [1] "2022-Q1-90" "2022-Q2-91" "2022-Q1-90"

# Now convert back to Date
as.Date(yqd)
#> [1] "2022-03-31" "2022-06-30" "2022-03-31"
```